# Two seaborn plots with different scales displayed on same plot but bars overlap

Tags: python, seaborn

I am trying to include 2 seaborn countplots with different scales on the same plot but the bars display as different widths and overlap as shown below. Any idea how to get around this?

Setting dodge=False, doesn't work as the bars appear on top of each other.

[image]

Comment: Please provide a minimal, complete, and verifiable example including input. Do not post code, data, error messages as images.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main problem of the approach in the question, is that the first `countplot` doesn't take `hue` into account. The second `countplot` won't magically move the bars of the first. An additional categorical column could be added, only taking on the 'weekend' value. Note that the column should be explicitly made categorical with two values, even if only one value is really used.

Things can be simplified a lot, just starting from the original dataframe, which supposedly already has a column `'is_weeked'`. Creating the `twinx` ax beforehand allows to write a loop (so writing the call to `sns.countplot()` only once, with parameters).

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

sns.set_style('dark')
# create some demo data
data = pd.DataFrame({'ride_hod': np.random.normal(13, 3, 1000).astype(int) % 24,
                     'is_weekend': np.random.choice(['weekday', 'weekend'], 1000, p=[5 / 7, 2 / 7])})
# now, make 'is_weekend' a categorical column (not just strings)
data['is_weekend'] = pd.Categorical(data['is_weekend'], ['weekday', 'weekend'])
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(16, 6))
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
for ax, category in zip((ax1, ax2), data['is_weekend'].cat.categories):
    sns.countplot(data=data[data['is_weekend'] == category], x='ride_hod', hue='is_weekend', palette='Blues', ax=ax)
    ax.set_ylabel(f'Count ({category})')
ax1.legend_.remove()  # both axes got a legend, remove one
ax1.set_xlabel('Hour of Day')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.countplot on twinx ax]

Answer (score 0):

**use plt.xticks(['put the label by hand in your x label'])**

Comment: I don't want to downvote the answer of a new user but how would that even address the question of overlapping bars?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).